# "Value does not exist" (WW CadLib)

Tags: c#

I think this is a rather straightforward issue, but I don't have much information to go on. I have this code to try and read a DWG file into memory, so that I can read and manipulate the data. I am getting an error that the parameter "Value" cannot be null.

While that does let me know something is wrong, how do I proceed in figuring out what exactly this value is so that I can fix it?

```cs
string basePath = Path.Combine($"{Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)}", "temp");
string fileName = Path.Combine(basePath, "ATemplateV0.2.dwg");

if(File.Exists(fileName))
{
       DwgReader dwgReader = new(fileName);

       try
       {
           DxfModel dxfModel = dwgReader.Read();
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WW CadLib` needs a license to run, if you don't have one that may be causing the error.

The code example in the answer from **@b166er** is referring to an **Open Source** library called `ACadSharp` to read dwg/dxf files from one of my repositories.

Right now you can use a pre-release version of it in [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ACadSharp/1.2.1-alpha)

Comment: We have a trial license at the moment, I just didn't know I needed to refresh it each day I wanted to use it. Which was causing it to fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a onNotification event into the DwgReader constructor that might give you more information. Examples here: https://github.com/DomCR/ACadSharp/blob/master/ACadSharp.Examples/Program.cs

Comment: Does not look like I can, There are only 2 signatures for the constructor. One taking a string and the other a Stream property. I am using the .NET Standard 2.0 library. Is it possible this library itteration is outdated?

Comment: It could be outdated yes, also have you tried a different test file?

Comment: Just did the same operation with a different file. Same result... I tried importing the newer versions 4.0 and 5.0 into the framework we use and those just threw compiler errors on resolving them. I guess replacing the library with a different version won't be possible. Or could this be because we are using a trial version?

Comment: Could you perhaps wrap the read in a try catch and provide the exception stack trace? Let's see if that gives more detail.

Comment: That did give some info. Appearantly you need to refresh the Trial license each day you use it... That part of it works now. Now I just need to actually perform what needs to be done on it